# Download external pdf files to chrome packaged app's file system

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is there any way to save pdf files from server to chrome packaged app?

In my chrome packaged app, i have some thing like this,

Download

when user clicks on this hyper link, i should able download that pdf file into my chrome packaged app file system.

Comment: Just to be clear, your question might be interpreted as asking how to put an additional file into the CRX-based file layout of the app. That cannot be done, by design. Chrome Apps are immutable.

Comment: Thanks Sowbug. This is my scenario. When user clicks on hyper link which has pdf file link in it, I should be able to download that file to chrome app file layout say I have 'pdf-downloads' folder within chrome app file layout. So that I am going to display all pdf which user downloaded so far using nice UI interface.Is this possible? or should I download pdf files to local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special about downloading PDF files. Use `XMLHttpRequest` to download a file, and then use the file APIs to either write it to a sandboxed file, or to an external file whose `FileEntry` you get with `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`.

Once downloaded, you can display the PDF in a webview or provide a link to open it in an external browser if you first convert it to a data URL with `FileReader.readAsDataURL`. (You can't reference the downloaded file as `file://` URL.)

(Chrome Apps should not be referred to as "packaged" apps, as the latter term refers to a now-obsolete legacy app technology.)

Update: To save the downloaded blob to a file:

```
// Save a blob in a FileEntry
// (e.g., from a call to chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry)
function saveToEntry(blob, fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(
        function(writer) {
            writer.onerror = errorHandler; // you supply this
            writer.truncate(0);
            writer.onwriteend = function () {
                writer.write(blob);
                writer.onwriteend = function () {
                    // blob has been written
                };
            };
        },
        errorHandler // you supply this
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for valuable response Marc. It helps me lot. One quick question : chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry API needs user interaction  right? It opens a file chooser dialog. When the user does choose a file, the FileEntry object passed to callback or else the parameter passed to call back will be null. How do i get 'FileEntry' Object in my case?

Comment: Sagar: I'd be happy to help, but I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to get a FileEntry when you use XMLHttpRequest? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I am able to download the file using XMLHttpRequest.After that how do I pass FileEntry object to chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry?

Comment: Consider following code:

xhr.onload = function(e)
   {
      if (this.status == 200)
      {
         var pdf = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
      }
   }

In my case, is var pdf is FileEntry?

Comment: No, it is not a FileEntry. It is an object URL. To save the blob, see the update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for update Marc. I tried ur code, it says " Cannot read property 'createWriter' of undefined". When we write the blob where  does it get saved?

Comment: Make sure the fileEntry passed to the fcn is defined. It can some from chooseentry, in which case the file your save to is the one chosen by the user. This is all explained in my new O'Reilly book.

Comment: While debugging, I see 'chrome.fileSystem' is undefined.I have given permission for file system in manifest.json.Getting followin error 'Cannot read property 'chooseEntry' of undefined'

Comment: Thanks Marc for support.I am able to download the file now.One quick questions : can we save file without user prompt where to save? can i save files within the chrome app's file system?

Comment: You can save to the sandboxed file system with no user interaction, but saving to the user-visible file system requires a call to chooseEntry.

Comment: Okay.I am going to save files to sand boxed file system without user interaction.Can you provide me references where I can find a way to implement?

Comment: I am using following code to get my download folder of chrome sand boxed file system.Console.log is not being called at all.

chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry( function(directoryEntry) {
directoryEntry.getDirectory('downloads', function(subDirectoryEntry) {
  console.log('Inside Download folder');
});

Comment: Post all of the code for a small app the illustrates the problem. All HTML, JavaScript, and manifest.json. It is difficult, if not impossible, to debug a code fragment.