# Access downloaded pdf file path in HTML5 file system and display it in webview

Tags: google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

In my chrome app, I am using HTML5 file system to save the pdf files to sand box.Downloading is working fine.But how do i access that downloaded file path? I want to give that path as webview source.

Comment: Could you show your relevant code on how you save the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way, if it works, would be to use a filesystem URL. To get this use [`FileEntry.toURL`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/#widl-Entry-toURL-DOMString)

These don't work on external files (i.e. files that come from `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` and are outside the app's sandbox) but should work for files in the app's sandbox.

Note, I am referring to filesystem:// urls not file://urls, which won't work as Marc Rochkind has pointed out in his answer.

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this, but I believe it should work.

Comment: Nope. You can't use "file://" URLs.

Comment: @Marc I was referring to filesystem:// urls, not file:// urls. These are URLs which refer directly to items in sandboxed file systems. Read the link to FileEntry.toURL provided for more information. Because these are sandboxed and only accessible by the origin that created them, they don't have the same restrictions as file:// URLs.

Comment: @Marc if you -1'd my answer could you consider un -1ing it?

Comment: System won't let me unless the answer is edited. Edit it and I'll add the 1 back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the contents of the PDF into a data URL. See my answer to this question:

[Download external pdf files to chrome packaged app's file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910077/download-external-pdf-files-to-chrome-packaged-apps-file-system/26912867#26912867)